# How to know when field or property initialization is done?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example, there's two classes here.
Class One:

```cs
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public class One:MonoBehavior
    {
        private List<string> _assetBundleList;
        
        private void Start()
        {
            InitializeList();
        }
        
        private void InitializeList()
        {
            //Add assetBundleList field some value.
        }
        
        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _assetBundleList.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Class two:

```cs
    public class Two:MonoBehavior
    {
        public GameObject gameObjectWithScriptOne;
        private One _scriptOne;
        
        private void Start()
        {
            scriptOne = gameObjectWithScriptOne.GetComponent<One>();
            DoSomething();
        }
        
        private void DoSomething()
        {
            foreach(var assetBundle in scriptOne)
            {
                //Load asset
            }
        }
    }
```

Script one is just like a manager things, I use this for storing asset bundle data, perhaps the list value will change. Script two must wait for initializing done. Is there any way to wait for it except adjusting script order?

Comment: What do you mean?  Wait for what?  There's no multi-threading here nor is it required.   What you ask is just fundamental C#

Comment: I need the list value in script one to be assigned and then use in script two. I konw it's basic thing in c# but not unity. Without adjusting script order can't ensure which one will run first.

Comment: he couldn't described it nicely but his intent is very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be handled with easily creating a context that initialize things sequentially. In short you need to block the main thread.

Let's say you have a root or persistent scene that do must things like loading assets etc.

```
//The only object in the Root Scene.
public class RootContext : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string _playerAddress = "Player";

    public void Awake()
    {
        //Load assets
        //wait for assets loading
        //instantiate things.
        //new instantiated things can also initalize with this way.
        var handle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(_playerAddress);
        var asset = handle.WaitForCompletion();
        var go = Instantiate(bla bla bla);
    }
}
```

I think the what you want is a framework that organize things. You can look at [Strange](https://strangeioc.github.io/strangeioc/). It is MVCS + IoC framework. Addionality what you said about "when field or property initialization is done" with `[PostConstruct]` attribute with Strange.

```
    [Inject(ContextKeys.CONTEXT)]
    public IContext Context { get; set; }

    /*Initialization of injections are guaranteed at here. Their initialization 
    is also quaranteed like this class.
    */
    [PostConstruct]
    public void Initalize()
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with refactoring, but if this is not the case C# events might be the solution.

Class One

```cs
public class One:MonoBehavior
{
    private List<string> _assetBundleList;
    public event Func Initialized;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        InitializeList();
    }
    
    private void InitializeList()
    {
        //Add assetBundleList field some value.
        Initialized?.Invoke();
    }
    
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _assetBundleList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Class Two:

```cs
public class Two:MonoBehavior
{
    public GameObject gameObjectWithScriptOne;
    private One _scriptOne;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        scriptOne = gameObjectWithScriptOne.GetComponent<One>();
        scriptOne.Initialized += DoSomething;
    }
    
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        foreach(var assetBundle in scriptOne)
        {
            //Load asset
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should unsubscribe from events when disabling an object, but you'll figure it out by yourself.

Comment: That's just making it _more_ complex.

Comment: Yeah, I need load in many place so I can't subscribe event in every class.

Comment: Well use Dependency Injection then so your class One will be instantiated before other classes (or you can use jit injection to perform lazy method) and could be injected from DI container by just using an `[Inject]` attribute on your field. Take a look at https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject maybe this will fit your needs

Comment: The last thing you want to use in a game is DI and their overly complicated, indeterminate behaviour that creates more problems than they solve.

Comment: I think it depends on your preferred project architecture, but sometimes it's just an unneeded overengineering, indeed. I personally don't see any _good_ solutions besides events (_yet, I got -1 and zero alternatives_), even by changing the script loading order and their timings, there is a chance that the first class will not have time to initialize the data by the time the second class tries to access it, cuz it loads asset bundles, which can be huge. The simplest solution is to add some field like `isInitialized` and wait for it to change in a while loop, but I'd still choose events.

Comment: All right, I thought I get the point. I will try in both ways. Thanks for your helping! Have a good day!